# Ошибка "Filed definition not allowed after methods or properties". Что делать?

Tags: delphi

```
 type q = class(Tobject)

function  q1(x:integer)): pointer;
procedure q2(x:integer);
function  q4(x:integer): integer;
procedure q4;

    private
        function X(x:integer):integer;
        w,h:integer;    src,buf: hdc;  <---------- 3десь
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе, в различных его разделах (приватных, публичных, например), надо сначала определять переменные класса, а потом уже только его методы:

```
 type q = class(Tobject)

 function  q1(x:integer)): pointer;
 procedure q2(x:integer); function 
 q4(x:integer): integer; procedure q4;

     private
         w,h:integer;    src,buf: hdc;
         function X(x:integer):integer;
     end;
```

Comment: Благодарю!